# How to retrieve values from a json file in a particular order?

Tags: python, json

I am new to python. I am writing a code, where I need to read the json file, and dump some of it's data to a new json file.
Following is my code:

```
if vmName=='IGW':
    with open(APIJSONPath+NwIntfJSONFileName) as f:
        data=json.load(f)

    for item in data['Interfaces']:
        jdata=item
    with open(NwIntfJSONPath+vmName+'.json','w') as c:
        json.dump(jdata,c,indent=2)
```

Following is a small part of my json file data from which this code is supposed to retrieve the interface details(Interface name,IPAddress, PrefixLength, DefaultGateway) of eth0 and eth1:

```
{
    "Interfaces": [{
                    "Name": "eth0",
                    "IPConfigurations": [{
                            "IPAddress": "10.0.3.7",
                            "PrefixLength": 24,
                            "DefaultGateway": "10.0.3.1",
                            "IsPrimary": true
                    }],
                    "Description0": "connected to cloudsimple network",
                    "IsPrimary": true
           } ,
            {
                    "Name": "eth1",
                    "IPConfigurations": [{
                            "IPAddress": "10.0.3.8",
                            "PrefixLength": 24,
                            "DefaultGateway": "10.0.3.1",
                            "IsPrimary": true
                    }],
                    "Description1": "connected to internet"
            }
      ]
}
```

But the data that is getting dumped the new json file is:

```
{
  "Name": "eth1",
  "IPConfigurations": [
    {
      "PrefixLength": 24,
      "IsPrimary": true,
      "IPAddress": "10.0.3.8",
      "DefaultGateway": "10.0.3.1"
    }
  ],
  "Description1": "connected to internet"
}
```

Only eth1 details is getting dumped, not the eth0. The dumped data is also in an unordered manner.

Can someone please help me figure out, where I am going wrong, and how to fix this two issues in my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think your loop will keep the information for both interfaces?

Answer (score 2):

If you need all content of *data['Interfaces']* in your output json use the below snippet.

```
if vmName=='IGW':
    with open(APIJSONPath+NwIntfJSONFileName) as f:
        data=json.load(f)

with open(NwIntfJSONPath+vmName+'.json','w') as c:
    json.dump(data['Interfaces'],c,indent=2)
```

In your example you are looping through data['Interfaces'] and jdata holds the last value of the list. That is why you are only getting the last element in the output json.

Comment: But the entire information is inside a single list, so shouldn't it iterate through the elements, one at a time?
Plus, please also guide me, how to preserve the original Json format while dumping the data to the new json file.

Comment: @Asish; No you do not need to iterate over the list. You can just call the key of the list to fetch all content of the list. Is the above snippet not working for you?

Comment: Yes it is working, but I am not able to maintain the sequence of the data since it is a dictionary. Can you help me out a bit more please?